# How do I create a regex for ipaddress to be used with other patterns in PL SQL

Tags: regex, plsql, ip-address

I need to write a regular expression in order to be able to match the following patterns:

```
IF:en0 

IF:en0:10.94.80.78

IF:en11

IF:en11:10.94.80.78
```

The regular expression i wrote in PL SQL was

```
IF REGEXP_LIKE(input_str,
'^IF:en([0-9])([:]?)((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})$') then  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Match');
END IF;
```

This works fine. But I want to know if there is a way in which I can make the pattern for ip address

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})
```

as a variable above and use something like

```
ipaddrpattern :=
  '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})';

IF REGEXP_LIKE(input_str,
'^IF:en([0-9])([:]?)||ipaddrpattern||$') then  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Match');
END IF;
```

I tried the above but didn't work. Can someone please help me with the syntax?

Comment: Is there a reason you *must* verify that all of the octets are valid in SQL itself? Seems like it would make more sense to just use a much more basic pattern that can match any 1-3 digit number in each octet, and instead verify the data before it makes it into the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to concatenate your pattern :)
Use

```
'^IF:en([0-9])([:]?)' || ipaddrpattern || '$') then
```

instead of

```
'^IF:en([0-9])([:]?)||ipaddrpattern||$') then
```

Your current implementation would match

`'IF:en1ipaddrpattern'`